# hadoop distcp fail over hftp protocol

Tags: hadoop, connection, hadoop2, distcp

I want to use distcp over hftp protocol to copy file from cdh3 and cdh4.
The command is like: 
`hadoop distcp hftp://cluster1:50070/folder1 hdfs://cluster2/folder2`

But the job fails due to some `http connection error` from jobtracker UI

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp: FAIL test1.dat : java.io.IOException: HTTP_OK expected, received 503 
    *at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HftpFileSystem$RangeHeaderUrlOpener.connect(HftpFileSystem.java:376)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.openInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.getInputStream(ByteRangeInputStream.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.ByteRangeInputStream.read(ByteRangeInputStream.java:187)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.copy(DistCp.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:547)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp$CopyFilesMapper.map(DistCp.java:314)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)*
```

Most files in folder1 will be copied to folder2 except some files fail due to the exception above.
Anyone has the same problem with me, and how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HFTP uses HTTP web server on datanodes to get data. Check if this HTTP web server is working on all the datanodes or not. I got this exact error and after debugging I found out this web server on some data nodes wasnt started due to some corrupt jar file.

This webserver is started when you start a datanode. You can check initial 500 lines of datanode log to see if thi webserver is starting or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your Hadoop cluster cluster1 and cluster2 running same version of Hadoop? What's the detail release version?
2. Any security setting you enabled on Hadoop?
3. HTTP return code 503 is server temporarily unavailable, is there any network issue happened during your copy?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  1. They are running on different hadoop versions, 0.20.2 and cdh4.4.0.  2. I don't know the security setting. But I can use hadoop dfs -ls hftp://cluster1:50070/folder1 on cluster2 and it can list the files. I think the hftp is unstable and there is temporarily server unavailable sometimes.  So is there any configuration I missed?

Comment: It's said that distcp might not work among two different hadoop versions. I think cdh 4.4 uses open source Hadoop 2.0 core packages, check [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDHTarballs/3.25.2013/CDH4-Downloadable-Tarballs/CDH4-Downloadable-Tarballs.html). Or please test the hftp along to see if it's stable enough.